# Angular 4 : Custom Components "Controls"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating an angular custom drop-down list component to use it as a control in all my pages.

Here's the HTML Template:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value">
        <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's the Typescript code behind it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html'
})
export class DropdownComponent {
    @Input() list: LookupModel[];

    @Input()
    value: LookupModel;

    @Output()
    valueChange: EventEmitter<LookupModel>;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.valueChange = new EventEmitter();
    }

    select(value: LookupModel) {
        this.valueChange.emit(value);
    }
}
```

And here's how I Use it:

```
<dropdown [list]="projectsList" [(value)]="selectedProject"></dropdown>
```

This component is working fine.
I want to create a change event handler like the one below:

```
<select name="projectField" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" (change)="filterBuilding()">
     <option [ngValue]="project" *ngFor="let project of projectsList">{{project.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

can anyone help me please? Is there a way to include the normal HTML event handlers in my custom control? Or I'll just have to handle it all manually?

If I'll have to handle it manually, how to send a method where I just send a pointer to my function and the role of this method is to execute any function that is passed to it?

Thanks.
I need the final output of the control to be like that:

```
<dropdown [list]="projectsList" [(value)]="selectedProject" (change)="filterBuilding()"></dropdown>
```

Comment: change (ngModelChange)="filterBuilding($event)" instead of  (change)="filterBuilding()" your custom html

Comment: <dropdown [list]="projectsList" [(value)]="selectedProject" (ngModelChange)="filterBuilding($event)"></dropdown>, the event doesn't get fired

Comment: <dropdown [list]="projectsList" [values]="selectedProject" (select)="filterBuilding($event.value)"></dropdown> try this.

Comment: this almost made it work, however i still needed to register a (change) event in my html template that's rendering the dropdown and then emit it. worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngModelChange` to detect the change on your model:

```
(ngModelChange)="filterBuilding($event)"
```

Comment: <dropdown [list]="projectsList" [(value)]="selectedProject" (ngModelChange)="filterBuilding($event)"></dropdown>, The event doesn't get fired

Comment: @Willy You should set the model. Where is your ngModel?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, In the HTML template for the dropdown i added (change) event

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="valueChange(value)">
        <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

and in the typescript code i told the valueChange method to emit the function:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html'
})
export class DropdownComponent {
    @Input() list: LookupModel[];

    @Input()
    value: LookupModel;

    @Output()
    onChange: EventEmitter<any>;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.onChange = new EventEmitter();
    }

    valueChange(value: LookupModel) {
        this.onChange.emit(value);
    }
}
```

And this is how i use it now:

```
<dropdown [list]="projectsList" [(value)]="selectedProject" (onChange)="filterBuilding($event)"></dropdown>
```